# Kotlin Multiplatform: "Fatal error: module 'TensorFlowLiteObjC' not found"

Tags: kotlin, gradle, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m trying to integrate TensorFlowLiteObjC into a KMM static library, but it’s not working I have the suspicion that I need to link the TensorFlowLiteC library with the TensorFlowLiteObjC library through cocoapods but I’m not fully sure.

Cocoapods configuration

```
  cocoapods {
    summary = "Core SDK Module"
    homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
    ios.deploymentTarget = "14.0"
    framework {
      baseName = "Core"
      isStatic = true
    }

    pod("TensorFlowLiteObjC") {
      version = "~> 2.10.0"
    }
    useLibraries()
  }
```

Error when I'm trying to build the project (`./gradlew clean build`):

```
> Task :core:cinteropTensorFlowLiteObjCIosArm64 FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /var/folders/q9/kc2cwb813l7_d9x4n5y78b1h0000gn/T/6134897582236622275.m:1:9: fatal error: module 'TensorFlowLiteObjC' not found
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:274)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesASTFiles(ModuleSupport.kt:75)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.ModuleSupportKt.getModulesInfo(ModuleSupport.kt:14)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.buildNativeLibrary(main.kt:516)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:285)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLibSafe(main.kt:214)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:80)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:40)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:62)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In my recent experience, running the `commonizeCInterop` gradle task would sometimes unblock this for me, it was very finicky.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting the same error :(

I'm considering trying to build TensorFlow library statically.

Comment: Please read https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52070/Cocoapods-Cinterop-error-Module-not-found, does it help?

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov thanks for the reply. I'll take a look tomorrow. It looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still looking for an answer
You need to specify the module name for the TensorFlow pod (usually you can find it inside the library's `module.modulemap` file).

```
pod(name = "TensorFlowLiteObjC", moduleName = "TFLTensorFlowLite", version = "2.11.0")
```

then you can import and use it like this

```
import cocoapods.TFLTensorFlowLite.TFLInterpreter
import cocoapods.TFLTensorFlowLite.TFLInterpreterOptions
...
val errorPointer = alloc<ObjCObjectVar<NSError?>>().ptr
val options = TFLInterpreterOptions()
val interpreter = TFLInterpreter(modelPath, options, errorPtr)
...
```